# NGINX Rewrite URL String

Tags: nginx

I tried to use the rewrite function of NGINX to change one word from an URL string and I can't see to find any solution. Basicaly I need the word "png" to transform into "jpeg".

My variant was this and it did't work.

```
location ~ ^/qtb/([^/]+)/?(.*)$
{
if ( $args ~* ^(.*)/png(.*)$ )
{
rewrite $args $1/jpeg$2;
}
}
```

I want to transform this URL:

http://localhost:8089/qtb/judete?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&BBOX=349315.4219913930865,383373.4878520779312,486851.8865988351172,542404.8925680443645&CRS=EPSG:3844&WIDTH=1022&HEIGHT=883&LAYERS=ro_judete_poligon&STYLES=&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&DPI=96&MAP_RESOLUTION=96&FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi:96

In to this URL:

http://localhost:8089/qtb/judete?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&BBOX=349315.4219913930865,383373.4878520779312,486851.8865988351172,542404.8925680443645&CRS=EPSG:3844&WIDTH=1022&HEIGHT=883&LAYERS=ro_judete_poligon&STYLES=&FORMAT=image%2Fjpeg&DPI=96&MAP_RESOLUTION=96&FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi:96

Comment: Try: `if ($request_uri ~* ^(/qtb/.*)png(.*)) { return 301 $1jpeg$2; }`

Comment: @RichardSmith That actualy worked very well! Wow. Thanks a lot. But I have a question if you would be kind to clarify. If I want to capture the whole 'FORMAT\=image\%2Fpng' not only the 'png' just to make sure othe requests dont get messed up, how would I write it? Because inside the regex code the '=' and '%' simbols makes it not behave properly.

Comment: Also is not working consistenly, like on chrome on my pc works well, but when I switched to firefox and on other device... it was not going well. Maybe I can give you the file itself of nginx configuration or any other informations that would be helpfull, idk. Just let my know when you are here... because I dont wanna bother you with noob questions that usualy are a piece of cake for you.

Comment: @RichardSmith here is the raw code https://pastebin.com/i6ga97vS

Comment: Try: `if ($request_uri ~* ^(/qtb/.*FORMAT=image%2F)png(.*)) { return 301 $1jpeg$2; }` - this does not need to be inside a `location` block - also, **always** reset the browser's cache between tests for consistent results. The code you pasted contains two similar locations - you should place the `if` block **outside** any `location` block until you get a working solution.

Comment: @RichardSmith I think it works in the background, because the link is changed but the error that I get is 'This site can’t be reachedlocalhost refused to connect.'

Comment: I think this happends because after i reload the website, it defaults itself to the local host port no on 8089 that i have set it up. But you may know better that if this solution would actualy work on a real website. This is just my guess.

Comment: Maybe there is a fix using rewrite instead of return? Or maybe the 'if' is the tricky part https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/